# Is there a way to delete a line in a text file if it matches a specific text?

Tags: ruby, loops, text-files, duplicates

My text file contains an email/password list to set up accounts. Once I've used an email and password combo I would like to erase it form the text file.

My text file looks like this:

```
email,pass
email,pass
etc..
```

once I've used the e/p combo I would like to delete it from the file:

```
File.open("yahoo_accounts.txt") do |email|
  email.each do |item|
    email, password = item.chomp.split(',')
    emails << email 
    passwords << password
    emails.zip(passwords) { |name, pass| 
        browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff

        #using the email and pass

        File.open("yahoo_accounts.txt", "w") do |out_file|
            File.foreach("yahoo_accounts.txt","r") do |line|
                out_file.puts line unless line == '#{name},#{pass}'
            end
        end
        browser.close
    end
end
```

The problem occurs when I try to delete them from the file. I get an "browser.rb:382:in `assert_exists': browser was closed (Watir::Exception::Error)",
but that might just be the browser closing.

If all the e/p's are extracted (meaning there is nothing to delete) in the beginning, how can I loop it to keep going, instead of ending in error after the first zip loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is not huge, you can read it into an array, modify the array and then write the array to the file, overwriting the previous contents.

**Code**

```
def remove_lines(fname, user_name, password)
  IO.write(fname, IO.read(fname).gsub(/^#{user_name},#{password}\n/, ''))
end
```

**Example**

Let's create some data:

```
text =<<_
Bubba,boar
Henrietta,vespa
Luigi,pink
Bubba,boar
Luigi,mauve
_
  #=> "Bubba,boar\nHenrietta,vespa\nLuigi,pink\nBubba,boar\nLuigi,mauve\n"
```

and write it to a file:

```
FName = "tmp"
IO.write(FName, text)
  #=> 61
```

We can confirm what we've written to file:

```
IO.read(FName)
  #=>  "Bubba,boar\nHenrietta,vespa\nLuigi,pink\nBubba,boar\nLuigi,mauve\n"
```

Now remove the lines for `user_name/password #=> Bubba/boar`:

```
remove_lines(FName, "Bubba", "boar")
  #=> 39
```

Let's confirm it worked by examining `FName`:

```
IO.read(FName)
  #=> "Henrietta,vespa\nLuigi,pink\nLuigi,mauve\n"
```

**Postscript**

If something goes wrong while writing the array to file, you may lose both the old file and the new file. For that reason, it is often good practice to write the array to a temporary file, then delete the original file, then rename the temporary file to the name of the original file.

Comment: I think this will work better, I'm going to try this out now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write and read to the same file at the same time like that; the first line you write, will clobber the rest of the file so you won't be able to read it anymore.

You should write the changes to a temporary file as you read the lines, then move the temp file to the original file at the end. Something like:

```
require 'tempfile'
require 'fileutils'

temp_file = Tempfile.new('foo')
begin
  File.open("yahoo_accounts.txt", 'r') do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
      temp_file.puts line unless line == '#{name},#{pass}'
    end
  end
  temp_file.close
  FileUtils.mv(temp_file.path, "yahoo_accounts.txt")
ensure
  temp_file.close
  temp_file.unlink
end
```